# Java TreeViewer SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT

Tags: java, swt, jface, treeviewer

I work on a Eclipse Plugin which have two `TreeViewer`, one of them with the parameter `SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT`. This looks like this:
[image: Plugin Screen]

As you see the Tree Structure is drawn from right to left and that is what i need. But and here is my problem, the Text gets also inverted but only when special characters are in the string.
`PID.5.7` is transformed to `7.5.PID`.
Here is how i create `TreeViewer` and the Text:

```
xmlTreeOut = new TreeViewer(composite, SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT | SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
...
xmlTreeOut.getTree().addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        //loop over treeItems and for each
        ...
        TextLayout textLayout = new TextLayout(Display.getDefault());
        textLayout.setText(xmlName + xmlValue);
        textLayout.draw(event.gc, root.getBounds().x + 2, root.getBounds().y + 1);
        ...
    }
});
```

Does anyone have a fix for this problem? I would like to have my String exactly as I write it in the `TextLayout`.

**EDIT:**

I added the mentioned

```
textLayout.setOrientation(SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Now my output is like this:

[image]

As you can see it worked for Strings like PID.7.5 but if there are Strings seperated with space and only containing special characters its inversed.
Like "MSH.1 |" becomes "| MSH.1"

(removed the Style2 and use only one style in TextLayout)

**EDIT 2:**

**WORKAROUND SOLUTION:**

I test now if my String starts with a "word" which has no a-z, A-Z I simply add a "x" with StyleColor = WHITE in front. This way all values are displeyed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but the method [`TextLayout#setOrientation(int orientation)`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/TextLayout.html#setOrientation%28int%29) looks like what you need:

> Sets the orientation of the receiver, which must be one of `SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT` or `SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT`.

Just set it to `SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT` for both `TreeViewer`s (or maybe `SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT` for the right `TreeViewer` to invert the previous right-to-left ?).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, yes i saw the setOrientation but did not tryed to set it again RIGHT_TO_LEFT. It works but only half way. I add a screen of the "new" result to my first post.

Comment: @Darkpara Hm, I can't think of a better solution than splitting on the space character, inversing the array, joining it again and the using it...

Comment: Would be a possiblity if it would be allways the same. See new screen, the String only gets inversed when a "word" contains only special characters, in the case with two words (normal chars) it does not inverse.. it's realy strange

Comment: @Darkpara Well that's annoying... Sorry, I'm running out of ideas here.

Comment: @Darkpara [This](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=77790) seems related.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I got it fixed with a workaround added to my question at end.